# How to disable auto reconnection to oracle DB?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

Im using hibernate to connect to a oracle database in my application. When the password for the oracle DB is changed, and when the application keeps hitting the DB for connection with the expired password, the DB gets locked after 3 failed tries. Is there a way to disable reconnecting to the DB automatically from the application? like how we use for MySql `autoReconnect=true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Into hibernate configuration file you can use following code .I think it will solve your problem

```
<property name="connection.autoReconnect"> false</property>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. But i get two connections: one from the MySQL database and another from Oracle DB. Will this be applicable to both the connections?

Answer (score 0):

You have two different config file so you can use configuration for both config file